# how to sort database with python

Tags: python, sqlite

how to sort database after inted the data to the database table using python

I just create some program with python imported tkinter like insert data to database after entrying some firstname and lastname to the input.
when I click insert button it will inert all data to table.
but I want to sort data by clicking the sort button. is that possible ?

```
def insertData():
    if  FIRSTNAME.get() == "" or LASTNAME.get() == "" or ADDRESS.get() == "" or USERNAME.get() == "" or PASSWORD.get() == "":
        txt_result.config(text="Please complete the required field!", fg="red")
    else:
        connection.Database()
        connection.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `member` (firstname, lastname, address, username, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (str(FIRSTNAME.get()), str(LASTNAME.get()), str(ADDRESS.get()), str(USERNAME.get()), str(PASSWORD.get())))
        connection.conn.commit()
        FIRSTNAME.set("")
        LASTNAME.set("")
        ADDRESS.set("")
        USERNAME.set("")
        PASSWORD.set("")
        connection.cursor.close()
        connection.conn.close()
        txt_result.config(text="Inserted a data!", fg="green")

    displayData()

def displayData():
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
    connection.Database()
    connection.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `member` ORDER BY `lastname` ASC")
    fetch = connection.cursor.fetchall()
    for data in fetch:
        tree.insert('', 'end', values=(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3],data[4] ,'****')) # <-- I need here to sort the datas
    connection.cursor.close()
    connection.conn.close()
```

I expect the output data.sort() to be sort all data in database but it will show me 'int' object is not iterable :(

Comment: Can you share the full traceback for the error?

Comment: well, that is possible. You'll have to write a function to sort your table according to the respective conditions/filters though

Comment: there are many of errors. but I just need the method to sort the database table like.
fisrtname / lastname
jack            johny
anna          marken
van            sero

want to sort it ...
how can I write that function to sort the table 
do you have any example for that ?
and thank you very much

Comment: @Smoody_x5: As it stands you should get the records `ORDER BY lastname`, didn't you? If you want `fisrtname / lastname` you have to extend your `ORDER BY` accordingly.